# docker image running error with `make` commands

Tags: docker, makefile, dockerfile, docker-image

I'm trying to build a docker image for my project.

The docker image could be found here: https://hub.docker.com/r/haipengzhang/merchant_score_project

The corresponding docker file is:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3

RUN apt-get update

RUN pip install lightgbm && \
    pip install docopt==0.6.2 && \
    pip install deap
```

When I try to run the project in this docker image with `make` commands under my project's repo:

```
docker run --rm -v /$(pwd):/home/xxx/ haipengzhang/merchant_score_project make -C /home/xxx/ clean
```

I get the following error: 
`docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"make\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.`

Could anybody please help?  Thanks!

Comment: You base image does not contain the `make` command. Install it with `apt-get install -y build-essential` if you intend to use it.

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks for the help. I'll try it but I'm feeling this is not the reason because I didn't do this in my previous projects and it worked just fine.

Comment: @Zeitounator Got the same error.. Any other ideas?

Comment: I have the feeling you actually did not try at all: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/4802658384db20375350a7620bef0fde

Comment: @Zeitounator I did add `RUN apt-get install -y build-essential` to the `Dockerfile` [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/haipengzhang/merchant_score_project/dockerfile)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The reason

I now know what happend here. When this question was originally asked, the image in question did not have the `make` command inside it.

Adding `RUN apt-get install -y build-essential` to the Dockerfile solves the issue. But, this image is built on dockerhub, so when the image was rebuilt after adding this instruction - it was not refreshed locally. You would actively need to pull the image again like I mention later in this answer.

I verified this, but rebuilding the image from your original Dockerfile definition and confirming that `make` is not in that image.

### Original answer text

I checked, and the image `haipengzhang/merchant_score_project` does infact have have the `make` command in the path `/usr/bin/make`, and it is executable. The user in the image is root, and I am able to start the make command just fine.

There is a little problem with your docker run command, but I do not think that it is related to the issue:

You should not preceed the `$(pwd)` command with a `/` in the volume mapping. Try this instead:

```sh
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/home/xxx/ haipengzhang/merchant_score_project make -C /home/xxx/ clean
```

The error that you are getting, idicates that the make command cimply cannot be found in the path or local working directory inside the image - if I try to pass a nonexisting command, I get the same error:

```sh
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/home/xxx/ haipengzhang/merchant_score_project blabla
```

I get the same output:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"blabla\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

This leads me to believe that there is something out of order with the revision of the image, I would be concerned that you do not have the latest image locally?

To refresh the local image:

```sh
docker image rm haipengzhang/merchant_score_project:latest
docker pull haipengzhang/merchant_score_project
```

You could try debugging the image with somthing like:

```sh
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/home/xxx/ haipengzhang/merchant_score_project which make
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/home/xxx/ haipengzhang/merchant_score_project ls -la /usr/bin/make
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/home/xxx/ haipengzhang/merchant_score_project ls -la /home/xxx
```

And see if you get some indication that something is out of place

Comment: Refreshing the local image did the trick!  And I really enjoyed the clear structure and the guidance in the answer. Many thanks for the help!!